# copying a folder from container running by using podman

Tags: copy, containers, podman

I have a jenkins container running inside a linux instance using podman.

I want to take the backup of the jenkins_home folder from within the container to my linux server.

Container name is jenkins

I am using the following command :

```
podman cp jenkins:/var/jenkins_home /home/ec2-user/
```

But i am facing the following error:

```
Error: 1 error occurred:
    * error determining run uid: user: unknown user error looking up user "jenkins"
```

Comment: Which Podman version are you using? The command `podman cp jenkins:/var/jenkins_home u jenkins /home/ec2-user/` has 4 arguments after "podman cp " but it looks like `podman cp` is expecting 2 arguments (see the man page https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-cp.1.html)

Comment: sorry , i have added extra "u jenkins" part , i have updated the question